# mysql date_sub using a field as interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with mysql and date_sub(). I have a table call Activity

```
Activity(id,deadline,alert)
Activity(1,'2011-04-18','1 DAY');
Activity(2,'2011-04-13','1 MONTH');
```

Every row in A have an 'alert', this field indicate how time before the deadline an activity have to reported.

For example

```
On 2011-04-17 I have to report the activity with 'id' 1
On 2011-03-14 I have to report the activity with 'id' 2
```

I trying to use `date_sub()` functions, but I can't use a field as params of this function. Any idea how to fix this?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `activities` 
 WHERE date_sub(`deadline`, INTERVAL alert) >= CURDATE();
```

Comment: If you can, change the table to do the calculation of the alert-date before inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the alert into 2 fields

```
Alert_count: integer
Alert_period: enum('hour','day','month','week')
```

And change the query like so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `activities` 
 WHERE CASE alert_period 
   WHEN 'hour' THEN date_sub(`deadline`, INTERVAL alert_count HOUR) >= CURDATE();
   WHEN 'day' THEN date_sub(`deadline`, INTERVAL alert_count DAY) >= CURDATE();
   ...
 END CASE
```

Comment: No need to split the alert in separate table fields. Split it like this:

WHERE CASE SUBSTRING_INDEX(alert, ' ', -1)
 WHEN 'DAY' THEN date_sub(deadline, INTERVAL SUBSTRING_INDEX(alert, ' ', 1) DAY) ...

Answer (score 2):

If the number of alerts is small, you could write out a `case`:

```
WHERE case 
      when alert = '1 DAY' then date_sub(`deadline`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
      when alert = '1 MONTH' then date_sub(`deadline`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
      ... etc ...
      end >= CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not allowed after INTERVAL, you can convert your all alert limit to day on one column.

```
Activity(id,deadline,alert)
Activity(1,'2011-04-18','1');
Activity(2,'2011-04-13','30');
```

and use as:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `activities` 
 WHERE date_sub(`deadline`, INTERVAL alert DAY) >= CURDATE();
```

Comment: Months are not all the same number of days, so this will get you a late alert in Feb and an early one in Dec.

Comment: oh, yes you are right! thanks, i deleted the "month" keyword. set your deadline for days (:

Answer (score 0):

Although this solution will work it's not the most efficient way of storing this data because each time you query for this data MySQL must look at the interval value in every row, compute it against deadline date and then return you the answer.

If you were to compute this information just before you insert the data and store `alert_date` as a `DATE` column then (assuming you index it too) it'd be very fast for MySQL to find the rows with a query like:

```
SELECT id FROM activity WHERE alert=CURRENT_DATE();
```

even more efficient (it'd allow it to be query cached):

```
SELECT id FROM activity WHERE alert="2011-04-23";
```